# Cannot access ssh forwarding port

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding

I have two servers. 
Server A has a public IP address (`43.24.24.29`). 
Server B has a private IP address (`10.10.10.1`).

Server A can connect to Server B by its public IP address
(maybe there are some static routes), so Server A can access Server B.

Now I want to use another PC to `ssh` to Server B,
so, in Server A, I added an ssh port forwarding:

```
[ldl@ServerA ~]$ sudo ssh -N -f -L 222:43.24.24.29:22 admin@10.10.10.1
```

Now it started in the server:

```
[ldl@ ServerA ~]$ ps -ef | grep ssh
root      10228      1  0 4th mon 13 ?       00:03:19 /usr/sbin/sshd -D
root      91304  10228  0 04:46 ?        00:00:01 sshd: ldl [priv]
ldl       91308  91304  0 04:46 ?        00:00:00 sshd: ldl@pts/0
root     100491      1  0 10:57 ?        00:00:00 ssh -N -f -L 222:43.24.24.29:22 admin@10.10.10.1
root     100501  10228  1 10:57 ?        00:00:00 sshd: root [priv]
sshd     100502 100501  0 10:57 ?        00:00:00 sshd: root [net]
ldl      100505  91309  0 10:57 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto ssh
[ldl@ServerA ~]$ netstat -tlnp | grep 222
(No info could be read for "-p": geteuid()=1000 but you should be root.)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:222           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 ::1:222                 :::*                    LISTEN      -
```

However, in my local PC, I try to ssh to Server A's port 222
and I get this "Connection refused" error:

```
aircrafts-MBP:~ ldl$ ssh root@43.24.24.29 -p 222 -vvv
OpenSSH_7.7p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 48: Applying options for *
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 43.24.24.29 is address
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 43.24.24.29 [43.24.24.29] port 222.
debug1: connect to address 43.24.24.29 port 222: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host 43.24.24.29 port 222: Connection refused
```

---

The `43.24.24.29` is my demo IP address.

---

**EDIT-01**

I tried the command:

```
ssh -N -f -L 2222:localhost:22 admin@10.10.10.1
```

When I connect it I get this error: `ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer`. 
Verbosely:

```
aircrafts-MBP:~ ldl$ ssh 43.24.24.29 -p2222  -vvv
OpenSSH_7.7p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 48: Applying options for *
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 43.24.24.29 is address
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 43.24.24.29 [43.24.24.29] port 2222.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/ldl/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/ldl/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/ldl/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/ldl/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/ldl/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/ldl/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/ldl/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/ldl/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/ldl/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/ldl/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.7
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
```

Comment: I think you have created a listening port on `10.10.10.1`. Maybe you were meaning to use `-R`.

Comment: Alternatively: If you are just trying to ssh via a hop, you can also ssh to the public machine, then ssh to the private machine from there. And consider `authbind` in place of sudo, for this use case.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor No this will not have created the listening port on `10.10.10.1`. It will have created a listening socket on `43.24.24.29` which when connected to will (by means of SSH) instruct `10.10.10.1` to open a connection to `43.24.24.29`.  It's accidentally a really inefficient way to forward  `43.24.24.29:222` to `43.24.24.29:22`

Comment: @PhilipCouling sorry my error, I find these options a little confusing. Does it forward port 222→22 via IP 10.10.10.1 ?

Comment: Yup.  Just so.   Fun way to test firewall rules but otherwise not practically useful.

Answer (score 1):

You've got a little confused about which IPs to When port forwarding there are two pairs of IP / ports:

```
<from IP>:<from PORT>:<to IP>:<to PORT>
```

If you only set one IP then this reads as

```
<from PORT>:<to IP>:<to PORT>
```

This gets confusing because the "from ip from port" to the ssh client and "to ip to port" are from the server.

Try this from Server A:

```
ssh -N -f -L 2222:localhost:22 admin@10.10.10.1
```

You can then

```
ssh  43.24.24.29:2222
```

This works because the SSH connection is from Server A to Server B.  So in the above command "localhost" refers to Server B.

Comment: I executed your `ssh -N -f -L 222:localhost:22 admin@10.10.10.1`, I still can not from my PC to ssh the Server A.

Comment: @aircraft firstly woops, I misread the port number.  You should use a larger one than `222` it should be larger than 1000.  Eg: 2222.  If you have further problems you might need to edit further detail into your question.

Answer (score 1):

When you make a forwarding for a remote host you have to do a Remote port forwading with the **-R** parameter instead of -L, that would make a tunnel locally (localhost); otherwise all the tunnels that you will be creating would be pointed to localhost. Moreover, you should be sure that in that you have the `GatewayPorts yes` parameter established in the `/etc/sshd_config` file of the **10.10.10.1** server, otherwise it will not make the forwarding.

Try this after ensuring that you have the GatewayPorts parameter as yes:

```
ssh -N -f admin@10.10.10.1 -R 222:43.24.24.29:22
```

And then (EDITED):

```
ssh admin@10.10.10.1 -p 222
```

Comment: Sorry my fault you are right @PhilipCouling it would be ssh admin@10.10.10.1 -p 222

Comment: I use the `ssh -N -f admin@10.10.10.1 -R 222:43.24.24.29:22` command get the warning:  `Warning: remote port forwarding failed for listen port 222`. and my PC can not connect too.

Comment: That is usually because the port 222 is already in use @aircraft

Answer (score 1):

The error on your first attempt is because your command made ServerA listening only on 127.0.0.1 which is the so-called “localhost” address, that is an address reachable only by itself. In practical terms, you can access ServerA’s port 222 only from ServerA itself.

Also, by specifying `-L 222:43.24.24.29:22` it would actually have ServerB (10.10.10.1) connect back to ServerA's port 22.. not very useful I suppose.

Your second attempt (the EDIT-01) is better, but it's still making ServerA listen on localhost only. Thus I cannot imagine what process may have received that connection towards ServerA's port 2222, clearly not an ssh server. You may need to `kill` all `ssh -N ...` commands that may be present on your ServerA from your previous failed attempts, and also make sure that you use a port (2222 in the example) which must not be already in use.

Given all that, what you need to do is:

```
[ldl@ ServerA ~]$ ssh -N -f -L :2222:localhost:22 admin@10.10.10.1
```

The above tells ServerA to setup port 2222 (being above 1023 you don’t need to run it through `sudo`) to be listened to on **all** its addresses (note the `:` preceding 2222) and use the connection purposely established towards admin@10.10.10.1 (ServerB) to connect to *port 22 of **ServerB’s** “localhost”*.

That is how `-L` works: you tell it first what address and port (`:2222` on the above example) you want to setup on the “local machine” (ServerA on the above example) and where you want the **remote machine** to connect to. The “remote machine” being the one the ssh command connects to with the `admin@10.10.10.1` piece of syntax.

As awkward as it seems at first glance, keep in mind that ssh's port forwarding is not designed to be a good way to forward ssh protocol itself, even less as a solution for hopping from one host to another.

Therefore, if all you need to do is use ServerA as a hop to ServerB for your aircrafts-MBP, I would rather advise you to just do:

```
ssh -t root@43.24.24.29 'ssh admin@10.10.10.1'
```

directly from aircrafts-MBP.

Answer (score 1):

Your original attempt had two problems:

```
[ldl@ServerA ~]$ sudo ssh -N -f -L 222:43.24.24.29:22 admin@10.10.10.1
```

This runs the SSH as root, so the restriction to only listen on local port numbers >=1024 does not apply. But since you did not specify a `bind_address`, the SSH client followed the client-side GatewayPorts default setting, which is to listen on localhost only, and that's why you failed to connect to it from your PC.

Also, you specified the remote end of the tunnel as 43.24.24.29:22, so even if you could use the tunnel, it would just connect right back to ServerA's `sshd`.

To fix that:

```
[ldl@ServerA ~]$ sudo ssh -N -f -L "*:222:localhost:22" admin@10.10.10.1
```

The extra `*:` part tells the SSH client to allow connections into the tunnel from any IP address, not just from localhost. Double quotes are added to prevent the shell from doing a wildcard expansion on the asterisk. And the tunnel destination of "localhost:22" gets applied at the remote end of this SSH connection, which will already be at ServerB.

Then, on your PC, you should be able to do this:

```
aircrafts-MBP:~ ldl$ ssh root@43.24.24.29 -p 222
...possibly a SSH host key warning and/or a password prompt...
[root@ServerB ~]#
```

If it is not necessary to use port 222 specifically, using port number greater than 1023 would remove the need for `sudo`.

```
[ldl@ServerA ~]$ ssh -N -f -L "*:2222:localhost:22" admin@10.10.10.1

aircrafts-MBP:~ ldl$ ssh root@43.24.24.29 -p 2222
...possibly a SSH host key warning and/or a password prompt...
[root@ServerB ~]#
```

---

There is another way to skin this cat also. You could do this at your PC:

```
aircrafts-MBP:~ ldl$ ssh -L 2222:10.10.10.1:22 ldl@43.23.23.39
[ldl@ServerA ~]$
```

... to get an usable shell on ServerA while also forwarding to ServerB.

And then in another terminal window:

```
aircrafts-MBP:~ ldl$ ssh -p 2222 root@localhost
...possibly a SSH host key warning and/or a password prompt...
[root@ServerB ~]#
```

In this set-up, the first SSH session on the PC establishes a listening proxy in TCP/2222 on the PC, forwards all the traffic to ServerA, and then establishes a "plain" TCP connection from ServerA to port 22 of ServerB to pass on the traffic that enters the client's listening port. But since the second session using the proxy is also a SSH session, the hop from PC to ServerA will be SSH-within-SSH, and from ServerA to ServerB will be just SSH.

Comment: this works, so, you mean I should must create a connect from my PC to ServerA, right?